# Remove the extra plot in the matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I want to plot 5 data frames in a 2 by 3 setting (i.e. 2 rows and 3 columns). This is my code: However there is an extra empty plot in the 6th position (second row and third column) which I want to get rid of it. I am wondering how I could remove it so that I have three plots in the first row and two plots in the second row.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)

fig.set_figheight(8)
fig.set_figwidth(15)



df[2].plot(kind='bar',ax=axes[0,0]); axes[0,0].set_title('2')

df[4].plot(kind='bar',ax=axes[0,1]); axes[0,1].set_title('4')

df[6].plot(kind='bar',ax=axes[0,2]); axes[0,2].set_title('6')

df[8].plot(kind='bar',ax=axes[1,0]); axes[1,0].set_title('8')

df[10].plot(kind='bar',ax=axes[1,1]); axes[1,1].set_title('10')

plt.setp(axes, xticks=np.arange(len(observations)), xticklabels=map(str,observations),
        yticks=[0,1])

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: Plots]

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try this:

```
fig.delaxes(axes[1][2])
```

A much more flexible way to create subplots is the `fig.add_axes()` method. The parameters is a list of rect coordinates: `fig.add_axes([x, y, xsize, ysize])`. The values are relative to the canvas size, so an `xsize` of `0.5` means the subplot has half the width of the window.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Do you know how to move the two plots to the center?

Comment: If you want a subplot layout other than a regular grid, it is usually easier to use the `fig.add_axes()` method. It takes the coordinates of a rectangle (as a list) and returns a single axes object. The coordinates are relative to the window size. Il put an example in my answer.

Comment: Using `add_axes` is neither a very good nor recommended way of producing subplots. Either `plt.subplots` or `Gridspec` would be the ways to go and `delaxes` or `ax.axis("off")` can be used to delete or hide the subplot.

Comment: Can you please explain why? I understand that in most cases `plt.subplots` is sufficient, and then it is the recommended way. But in situations like this or if you want overlapping subplots I think this is the way to go.

Comment: Hi Johannes, What if I have defined my axes this way: f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4), (ax5, ax6), (ax7, ax8)) = plt.subplots(4, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True , figsize=(10,20)) and I don't need my ax8?

Comment: Sigh, unhappy with the inconsistent names `delaxes` and `add_axes`!

Comment: @Johannes I can't seem to make this work with the very first row of plots, ie `axes[0,2].set_axis_off()`. It throws a `ITypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable`. The subplots are 1 row of 4 columns.  Any pointers on how to implement this on the first row?

Answer (score 42):

Alternatively, using `axes` method `set_axis_off()`:

```
axes[1,2].set_axis_off()
```

Comment: I find this easier to implement than @Johannes suggestion when I don't know the number of rows/cols ahead of time

Comment: I can't seem to make this work with the very first row of plots, ie `axes[0,2].set_axis_off()`. It throws a `IndexError: too many indices for array`. The subplots are 1 row of 4 columns.  Any pointers on how to implement this on the first row?

Comment: In your case, axes is no longer a 2-D grid, it is a 1-D array of subplot objects. So you need to set `axes[2].set_axis_off()`.

Comment: '[p.set_axis_off() for p in [i for i in axes.flatten() if len(i.get_title()) < 1]] '

Answer (score 17):

If you know which plot to remove, you can give the index and remove like this:

```
axes.flat[-1].set_visible(False) # to remove last plot
```

Answer (score 9):

Turn off all axes, and turn them on one-by-one only when you're plotting on them. Then you don't need to know the index ahead of time, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(columns))

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_axis_off()

for c, ax in zip(columns, axes):
    if c == "d":
        print("I didn't actually need 'd'")
        continue

    ax.set_axis_on()
    ax.set_title(c)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 because it works best when I write a general plotting routine and don't know how many subplots there are going to be. All other answers were strictly correct w.r.t. the OP's question, but this is more generic.

Comment: -1 because it will not work if you add `sharex=True` in `subplots` call. Nether for other solutions like `delaxes` and `set_axis_off`.

Answer (score 6):

A lazier version of Johannes's answers is to remove any axes that haven't had data added to them. This avoids maintaining a specification of which axes to remove.

```
[fig.delaxes(ax) for ax in axes.flatten() if not ax.has_data()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Previous solutions do not work with `sharex=True`. If you have that, please consider the solution below, it also deals with 2 dimensional subplot layout.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,1, sharex=True)


plotted = {}
for c, ax in zip(columns, axes.ravel()):
    plotted[ax] = 0
    if c == "d":
        print("I didn't actually need 'd'")
        continue
    ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,6,7])
    ax.set_title(c)
    plotted[ax] = 1

if axes.ndim == 2:
    for a, axs in enumerate(reversed(axes)):
        for b, ax in enumerate(reversed(axs)):
            if plotted[ax] == 0:
                # one can use get_lines(), get_images(), findobj() for the propose
                ax.set_axis_off()
                # now find the plot above
                axes[-2-a][-1-b].xaxis.set_tick_params(which='both', labelbottom=True)
            else:
                break # usually only the last few plots are empty, but delete this line if not the case
else:
    for i, ax in enumerate(reversed(axes)):
        if plotted[ax] == 0:
            ax.set_axis_off()
            axes[-2-i].xaxis.set_tick_params(which='both', labelbottom=True)
            # should also work with horizontal subplots
            # all modifications to the tick params should happen after this
        else:
            break

plt.show()
```

[image: example run result]

2 dimensional `fig, axes = plot.subplots(2,2, sharex=True)`

[image: when using 2,2]